# Are questions about organizing video scripts and post-production on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Are questions about screenplay on-topic?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/937/11428), it seems that the answer is yes. We have questions about screenwriting. However, organizing video scripts and post-production may include music choice or edit techniques, which I'm not sure if they are still about writing or not.

Would that be on-topic? If yes, should we broaden the scope to explicitly include this?

Below is my draft.

---

I have a vlog to convey my thoughts in an important topic, in a form of a travel vlog, so that the video can be both contemplating, relaxing and exciting at the same time. It's like parallel narrative. I have the hook to begin the vlog, but I don't know how the transition after the hook should be before going back to the main topic.

I think the transition should:

- explain that I'm on a travel (the hook doesn't explicitly explain that)
- create positive mood (by showing interesting moments during the travel)
- be short enough (to not distract the main topic)?

In my vision, the format is similar to [this vlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EthqIhPtd2I). But for this vlog, the audience already expects that this is a travel vlog, so its transition only needs to show interesting things, and thus can be kept short (16 seconds). But my vlog is more complex, and I wonder how to keep the attentional span. I can still simply say "I'll discuss this in my travel" straightforwardly, but perhaps it will spoil the hook?

The transition doesn't need to show any logo (I don't need any brand).

Also, do you know which kind of music that suits the transition? I have visited Artlist and Epidemic but I still don't know how what music genres and moods that are relaxing and exciting on the surface, but also prepare the listeners some contemplations later on.

<sup>Related: [Would questions about brainstorming scripts on-topic?](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1554/25496) on Video Production</sup>

Comment: Brainstorming questions are generally not a good fit because they are just inviting opinions instead of expertise. Normally the [chat] is a good place to look for brainstorming ideas with others, but the chat here on Writing.SE is basically dead. You can still try to find others interested in the topic though.

Comment: Perhaps I have used the wrong word. My concern is about video, not brainstorming. I don't see how the example question be different to a question about rhetoric.

Comment: I'd say that asking about questions that pertain to a vlog script are on topic.  But the example you give is rather broad and asking for ideas.

Answer (score 3):

### Maybe…

If your question can be framed as [scriptwriting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scriptwriting), or focus on the [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative) and [structure](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) – in other words, the *content* of the video as an [essay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) or travel-lifestyle [journalism](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journalism) – it would be on topic.

There have been grey areas concerning (for instance) the visual design of comicbook characters, where the question concerns *narrative* and *character* rather than artstyle or technique.

### But…

The majority of Writing members are not video professionals. The question would likely provoke some pushback from members who would view it as off topic, and you may not get answers that understand the audiovisual medium – you will get *script-oriented* answers.

There is a [Video Production|SE](https://video.stackexchange.com) but it leans technical/hardware/software. Your question may not be a good fit there, but the members are more likely to be video professionals who could suggest media-savvy answers.

Comment: since the art style or technique of the media *ultimately* affects the narrative of the product, would that mean we should allow them too?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how such a question wouldn't be a question that has the intent of [generating ideas](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1272). As such, it would be off topic as:

> We're looking to avoid questions where the intent is [to generate ideas](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1272).

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have updated the question a little bit. Can you check that?